# Simulate 100 samples with n=25, mean=45, sd=4 in R

Tags: r

This is the code that I have

```
sample<-rnorm(25,45,4)
sample[1:100]
```

But it only returns a few samples and the rest come out as NA.

I am very new to R so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: `set.seed(2021); sample<-replicate(100, rnorm(25,45,4))` The seed is your choice, 2021 is just an example. But you should always set the pseudo-RNG seed in order to make the results reproducible.

Comment: Maybe `replicate(100, rnorm(25,45,4))` is more what you are after. But just dumping homework questions on Stack Overflow is strong discouraged. Make sure to ask a very specific programming question. Generally it's a good idea to first ask your teacher who is paid to help you learn and will be grading your homework if you need help.

Comment: rnorm(25,45,4) gives you not just "a few" but exactly 25 independant samples because that is just whan you have specified with n=25. If you want to get 100 samples out of the 25 then you should specify how exactly you want to resample them. Maybe rep(sample, 4) is just what you need, maybe you want to shufle them a bit, maybe there are some other requirements, maybe you actually just need 100 samples, maybe you need 100 times the 25 samples, or maybe you don't have a clue about what you actually need at all. Who knows...

Comment: Oh I dont need help answering the question. I just thought posting question would help but I just needed help simulating the samples to begin the question because my initial code was not coming out correct.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the parameters of rnorm() are just parameters of the whole distribution and are not necessary equal to the parameters of the limited amount of samples the rnorm() provides. set.seed(1); mean(rnorm(25,45,4)) for example gives the mean value of about 45.67, not the exact 45 you might be expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.
First, simulate the data with `replicate`, like I said in my comment. From `help("replicate")`:

> replicate is a wrapper for the common use of sapply for repeated evaluation of an expression (which will usually involve random number generation).

```
set.seed(2021)
data <- replicate(100, rnorm(25, 45, 4))
```

Now run the tests, results kept in a list.

```
alpha <- 0.05

ttest_list <- apply(data, 2, t.test, mu = 43, alternative = "less", conf.level = 1- alpha)
ttest_list[[1]]
#
#   One Sample t-test
#
#data:  newX[, i]
#t = 3.1329, df = 24, p-value = 0.9977
#alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 43
#95 percent confidence interval:
#     -Inf 47.38754
#sample estimates:
#mean of x 
# 45.83782 
#
```

If the `apply` loops are still not very clear to the OP, which frequently happens with new users of R, the following `for` loop might be a better option.

The tests list is created beforehand and filled with the tests results in the loop. Note the use of `seq_along`.

```
ttest_list2 <- vector(mode = "list", length = ncol(data))
for(i in seq_along(ttest_list2)){
  ttest_list2[[i]] <- t.test(data[, i], mu = 43, alternative = "less", conf.level = 1- alpha)
}
```

The extraction of values of interest can be done with `sapply`.

```
tstat <- sapply(ttest_list, '[[', 'statistic')
pvalues <- sapply(ttest_list, '[[', 'p.value')

tstat2 <- sapply(ttest_list2, '[[', 'statistic')
pvalues2 <- sapply(ttest_list2, '[[', 'p.value')
```

Both ways of conducting the tests are equivalent.

```
identical(tstat, tstat2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(pvalues, pvalues2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Not in the question:

```
hist(tstat, prob = TRUE)
```